# Taking vector norm from a data matrix in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to achieve some set of calculations using R for calculating the norm of a point with a given coordinate and then take the maximum and then take the square out of it.

I have tried the following:

```
a <- c(-0.5,1)
b <- c(-1,-1.5)
c <- c(-1.5,1.5)
d <- c(1.5,-0.5)
e <- c(0.5,-0.5)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

In a more detailed way, this is what I want to perform:

[image: task]

I tried using the `norm` and using the `Frobenius` but I want to put everything into a function to be used later. Because manually when I create vectors for these tasks it becomes too tedious to calculate every point. Looking for an efficient/simpler way to perform this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop `across` the columns, get the square of the elements, `sum` it, return with square root, get the `max` and square it

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ sqrt(sum(.^2)))) %>% 
   max %>%
   .^2
#[1] 4.5
```

---

In `base R`, we can use

```
max(sqrt(colSums(df^2)))^2
#[1] 4.5
```

If we want to `print` with all the digits, specify the `digits` in `print`

```
print(max(sqrt(colSums(df^2)))^2, digits = 16)
#[1] 4.499999999999999
```

Comment: Is there a need for `data.matrix()` for this computation which I posted in my question?

Comment: @RanjiRaj There is no need for this computation although there may be a performance improvement with matrix

Comment: Also, is there a way to keep the granularity of the output that I am getting actually, the value I get when I implement in python is `4.499999999999999` is it because of the underlying data structure that is doing this or can we have an actual representation of the value?

Comment: @RanjiRaj it could be due to some difference in precision adjustments in both software

Comment: @RanjiRaj Can you please check the update in my post